# how much time elapses from when the client clicks on the link until the client receives the object?

Tags: networking, tcp, dns

### Question

> Suppose within your Web browser you click on a link to obtain a Web page.
>   The IP address for the associated URL is not cached in your local host, so a
>   DNS lookup is necessary to obtain the IP address. Suppose that n DNS
>   servers are visited before your host receives the IP address from DNS; the
>   successive visits incur an RTT of RTT1, . . ., RTTn. Further suppose that the
>   Web page associated with the link contains exactly one object, consisting of a
>   small amount of HTML text. Let RTT0 denote the RTT between the local host
>   and the server containing the object. Assuming zero transmission time of the
>   object, how much time elapses from when the client clicks on the link until
>   the client receives the object?

#### My Attempt

When Client requests for Any HTTP service from Server the following Scenario takes place

> 1. DNS request from DNS client to DNS server for requested server's IP address.
> 2. After Recieving an IP address,A TCP Connection is initiated
> 3. After Initiation of TCP connection,Cient will Request HTTP CLient request to HTTP Server using the IP address Obtained after DNS reply.

I will calculate time based on the above scenario.

> In order to reach DNS Server to get IP Address we will require RTT1 + RTT2 +....+ RTTn .
>   .

Calculate time taken for TCP connection

> RTT0+RTT0=2RTT0

calculate time taken for Requesting object and recieving reply-:

> > RTT0+RTT0=2RTT0

Total time elapsed must be

> > > RTT1 + RTT2 +....+ RTTn +2RTT0+2RTT0=RTT1 + RTT2 +....+ RTTn .
> > >       +4RTT0

But answer is given as -:

> The total amount of time to get the IP address is
>   RTT1 + RTT2 +....+ RTTn .
>   Once the IP address is known, RTTO elapses to set up the TCP connection and another
>   RTTO elapses to request and receive the small object. The total response time is
>   2RTT0 + RTT1 + RTT2 +... RTTn

Where Am i Wrong?

Please help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need 1 RTT to set up the TCP connection. and then One more RTT to get that object.

Answer (score 0):

If its a non-persistent connection then you would need an RTT for the TCP connection then another for the HTML webpage request then another for an TCP connection (non-persistent) then finally for the object. 4RTT